# Solidity: How can a contract B, burn from contract A, generate another contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, remix

As we know if we want contract A, in the future, creates another contract: contract B, when we're deploying contract A, we also put the code of contract B in the transaction. So we send the following code to the blockchain to deploy contract A:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Contract_A {

address public b_addr;
function Contract_A(){

 }
  function create() {
    Contract_B bb = new Contract_B();
    b_addr = address(bb); }

function fetch(){
    Contract_B cc = Contract_B(b_addr);
    cc.change();}    
}

contract Contract_B {

  uint public val;
  function Contract_B(){
   val=7;}
   function change(){
   val+=90;}
  }
```

Assume, contract B wants to create another contract: contract C, in the future.

The **question** is: where should we put the code of contract C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something as follow on Remix IDE and it worked.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Contract_A {

address public b_addr;
function Contract_A(){

 }
  function create() {
    Contract_B bb = new Contract_B();
    b_addr = address(bb); }

function fetch(){
    Contract_B cc = Contract_B(b_addr);
    cc.change();}    
}

contract Contract_B {

    address public c_addr;
  uint public val;
  function Contract_B(){
   val=7;}
   function change(){
   val+=90;}

   function create() {

    Contract_C cc = new Contract_C();
    c_addr = address(cc); 

   }
}


contract Contract_C {

    //contract C code
}
```

AFAIK, you can either use a function defined in contract A to create a contract of B and call it (every time you call the function a contract B instance will be created ), or may be you can assign the address value of created contract B at the very first time and and check if the address is set whenever the function is called.

Comment: thanks for the answer! question: How can we interact with contract B (even in remix)? Do we need to mention both contractB and contractC? In general, when we are interacting with contractA, we need ABI of all three contracts; when we interacting with B, we need ABI of contract B and C, and when we interact with contract C, we need ABI of contract C?

Comment: AFAIK, you can either use a function defined in contract A to create a contract of B and call it (every time you call the function a contract B instance will be created ), or may be you can assign the address value of created contract B at the very first time and and check if the address is set whenever the function is called, this may look like singleton pattern and will not create B contracts every time you call. And if you return the value of B's address once it's created you can directly call B from may be web3 in that case you will need the ABI

Comment: Yes, I did; thanks. To interact with contract B or C, I used the approach explained my comment. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The one mentioned in my first comment: ... When I'm interacting with contract B deployed, I have to include ABI of contract B and C.

Comment: Great! Good luck :)