# Is it right to say: A contract account may contain more than one contract?

Tags: contract-design, accounts

My question is related to my previous question:

[Solidity: How can a contract B, burn from contract A, generate another contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/solidity-how-can-a-contract-b-burn-from-contract-a-generate-another-contract)

---

As we can in the aforementioned post when we are deploying contract A, we're including all contracts A, B, and C in a transaction sent to the blockchain. So the contract account will contain all the contracts codes (even though contract B and C are not born yet).

**Question**:  Is it right to say a contract account may contain more than one contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each contract will be deployed at a different address, even if ContractA references or holds a state variable of type ContractB.

So, no, your assertion is not true. When you deploy a contract, it will be assigned an address (what you are calling account). Even if that contract, internally, deploys N contracts, each those contracts will be deployed to a different address

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have no question about your answer, but it's still not clear to me where codes/references for contract B and C are stored when the contract A is deployed. Is it the case that codes of contract B and C are stored in contract A's account when contract A is deployed?

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Is it right to say a contract account may contain more than
>   one contract?

NO. It's only the contract A is deployed in that address and you won't be able to call contract B or C using the address of A directly.(Of course you can do it via function of A )

> So the contract account will contain all the contracts codes (even
>   though contract B and C are not born yet)

AFAIK, that code will be there for the reasons to be used when deploying B and that piece of code will define the interface of B to A (like ABI defines the interface to interact with a contract ).